# phpseclib: Validating signed data using certificate

Tags: php, encryption, x509, phpseclib

I do have a `private.pem` and `public.crt`.  my goal is to signed using `private.pem` and to verify its signature using `public.crt`. How do I achieve this by using phpseclib ?

```
$data = 'test';
$rsa = new RSA();
$privatekey = file_get_contents(storage_path('app/private.pem'));
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey); 
$signed = $rsa->sign($data);

$publickey = file_get_contents(storage_path('app/public.crt'));
$rsa->loadKey($publickey);

return $rsa->verify($data, $signed) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got my answer [here](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1259):

```
<?php
$data = 'test';
$rsa = new RSA();
$x509 = new X509();
$privatekey = file_get_contents(storage_path('app/private.pem'));
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);
$signed = $rsa->sign($data);

$publickey = file_get_contents(storage_path('app/public.crt'));
$x509->loadX509($publickey);
$rsa = $x509->getPublicKey();
return $rsa->verify($data, $signed) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
```